# multiple http calls issue on Ionic (Angular) crashing

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, httpclient, ionic5

I have list of items in template

```
<ion-list class="ion-text-center">
    <div *ngIf="farms$ | async as farmData">
      <ion-item (click)="selectFarm(farm)" *ngFor="let farm of farmData" detail="true" button>
        <ion-label>
          <h2>{{ farm?.name }}</h2>
          <p>{{getNumberOfAnimals(farm?.id) | async}}</p>
        </ion-label>
      </ion-item>
    </div>
</ion-list>
```

In each item I need to get number of Animals from separate endpoint, which is separate call

```
getNumberOfAnimals(id){
const url = (some link) + id;
return this.http.get(url).pipe(take (1))
}
```

What is the issue - it is calling endpoint numbers of times (non stop until page crushes).
Some of them even show as canceled.

**Do you have any ideas why and how to fix that?**

Comment: As a rule of thumb, you shouldn't call functions from within your DOM. Angular won't know when to recall the function, because no state check can be performed.

Comment: Best way to do this is check with your API team and try to handle this on api side and return everything on a single end point. Calling end points inside a loop will create a big performance issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my assumption for this answers

- You don't have an API which accepts multiple ids.
- FormData is not an observable.

In that case I would recommend you not to call this method as calling from html is like calling from ngViewChecked it will call multiple time. Better get the numbers before and hold it into the array and call this from your html.

Here is the sample code.

```
// declared  variables in component 
farmData: Array<any> = [];
numberOfAnimals: Array<any> =[];

  ngOnInit(){

    const ids = of(this.farmData.map(elem => elem.id));

    // do not forget to unsubscribe
    ids.pipe(
      concatMap((val)=>{
        return this.getNumberOfAnimals(val).pipe(map((elem)=>{
          const item = {
            id: val,
            number: elem,
          }
         return this.numberOfAnimals.push(item);
        }))
      })
    ).subscribe();
  }

  getNumberOfAnimals(val): Observable<any>{
    // your api call
    return of({number: 20})
  }

callFromYourHTML(id: number){
  return this.numberOfAnimals.find(elem => elem.id === id).number;
}
```

From your HTML call this

```
<ion-list class="ion-text-center">
    <div *ngIf="farms$ | async as farmData">
      <ion-item (click)="selectFarm(farm)" *ngFor="let farm of farmData" detail="true" button>
        <ion-label>
          <h2>{{ farm?.name }}</h2>
          <p>{{callFromYourHTML(farm?.id) | async}}</p>
        </ion-label>
      </ion-item>
    </div>
</ion-list>
```